# How to translate a config.ini file into C#.NET objects

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, object

config.ini:

```
[globalloads]
plugin.SWPlugin = 1
plugin.SWPlugin.params.1 = true
plugin.SWPlugin.params.2 = 10

[testz : globballoads]
plugin.SWPlugin.params.2 = 20
plugin.SWAnotherPlugin = 1
```

Simple enough?

```
// load testz config and programmatically create this equivalent code:
SWPluginAbstract p = new SWPlugin(true, 20);
// go thru the loop and load the other plugin too
SWPluginAbstract p = new SWAnotherPlugin();
```

If a different config.ini setup is needed to do that, it's not a problem...  I suspect I will need to use a reflection class of some sort?  I'm new to the whole .NET thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended mechanism for storing settings is to define custom ConfigurationSection's w/ custom elements and collections.  These can then be stored in machine.config, app.config and a few other places.

The easiest way to make these is with a Visual Studio add-in called "[Configuration Section Designer](http://csd.codeplex.com)" on CodePlex.com.

It's visual and does a good job of making configuration sections.

Comment: Ah I was looking for a more simple interface for people using the program with limited computer programming experience able to drop a line in there to autoload the plugins and such.  It's not really a program you run more than once with the same settings, so saving and loading them any other way than from something simple like an .ini is not, er.. desired.